# Tensor, How to Gather Values of a List of Index?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

```
t2 = tf.constant([[0, 11, 2, 3, 4],
                  [5, 61, 7, 8, 9],
                  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
valid_mask = t2 <= 10
validIndex  =  tf.where(valid_mask)
print('validIndex',validIndex) # Expectation = Reality

print()

print('Final Output',tf.gather(t2,indices=validIndex)) # Hmm.. What ?
```

My final output comes as

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[ 0 11  2  3  4]
  [ 0 11  2  3  4]]

 [[ 0 11  2  3  4]
  [10 11 12 13 14]]......

 [[10 11 12 13 14]
  [ 0 11  2  3  4]]], shape=(9, 2, 5), dtype=int32)
```

Expected

```
[0,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]
```

Please help to debug & correct and explain what's happening

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.gather_nd` or `tf.boolean_mask`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t2 = tf.constant([[0, 11, 2, 3, 4],
                  [5, 61, 7, 8, 9],
                  [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
                  [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
valid_mask = t2 <= 10
validIndex  =  tf.where(valid_mask)

print(tf.gather_nd(t2, indices=validIndex))
print(tf.boolean_mask(t2, valid_mask))
```

```
tf.Tensor([ 0  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10], shape=(9,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 0  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10], shape=(9,), dtype=int32)
```

Btw, your expected out should include the number 10 based on your condition.

Comment: Thanks, whats tf.gather suppose to do ?

Comment: Check https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather